# Python Unterminated quoted string

Tags: string, python-2.7

I started working with python and as I was trying to pass some arguments to *os.popen()* I keep getting

> Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

And it is not just on one place basically it happens everywhere, where I use lets say "complicated" arguments. 
For example:

```
path="/home/user/Desktop/"
video="Science Copies Nature's Secrets - Biomimicry-2d1VrCvdzbY.webm"
os.popen("(python -m json.tool "+PATH+video+"-something.json | grep \"ext\"\")")
```

I thought it is the **'** in *Nature's* that makes the problem but even after improving it to *Nature\'s* it is not working. 
Another thing that I have tried was to save the command in another variable and than call the os.popen(variable), but no result.

It is probably a stupid problem for the more experienced guys over here, but I would love some actual help or hints.

Comment: """  All good men/women blah blah blah ''' will throw this error as well.  Change to """ All good men/women blah blah blah """

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you don't need the parentheses, you need a space just before something and to surround the file with "". The following should work:

```
path = "/home/user/Desktop/"
video = "Science Copies Nature's Secrets - Biomimicry-2d1VrCvdzbY.webm"
os.popen("python -m json.tool \"" + path + video + "\" -something.json | grep \"ext\"")
```